# How to create a MetaData API in Salesforce

Tags: metadata-api, trailhead

I am Trying to complete Trailhead Challenge on Big Objects. to create a big object we need to use MetaData API. can any one explain me how to create a metadata API in Detail. does it similar like Apex class ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various [Salesforce IDEs](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Tools) use the Metadata API internally. All you have to do is to create the XML file that represents the Big Object and leave it to your IDE to push that into the org. There is an example of such a file in the [Define Custom Big Objects](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/big_objects/units/big_objects_define_custom_big_objects) Trailhead unit.

(The Metadata API is [stable and documented](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf) and can be called from any programming language that has SOAP support including [Apex](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). But mostly it is development tool authors or developers who want to automate specific org configuration updates who need to do that.)

Comment: Thanks Keith for providing more information regarding Metadata API. now i got how to deal with Metadata.